# DocuSign - Multiple APIUserEmail and Password for Same IntegratorsKey

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi

I have four different projects that I run thru the same app, and they have four different email accounts from which the documents are sent out and managed. All four projects are unrelated to each other.

Is there a way that I can programatically call APIUserEmail and Password from Web.Config? The IntegratorsKey and APIAccountId are the same for all four projects.

I tried it by using different key names for each project and supplying that string to the call, but that did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you using the DocuSign SDK from Github? If so, what language are you using? Can you post some sample code on what you've tried?

Comment: I am using DocuSign API using SOAP in C#. My code works, but I have to manually comment out three of the four APIUserEmail and Password in Web.Config, based on which project I am processing the data for. This is error-prone and I cannot have a user do the processing, as they cannot access the code.

Comment: So you are using the DocuSign SDK or you're using your own custom code? This isn't really a DocuSign question, as it is a how do I use a custom variables conditionally. Which should be done probably through if statements.

Comment: I thought it is DocuSign because the Web.Config parameters are for DocuSign and not sure if there is a way to change their key names to project specific key names so that I can call them conditionally.

Comment: As Andrew says, this is not a DocuSign question.  What this boils down to is, you want to dynamically select values from your web.config file.  The fact that the values in question are DocuSign usernames and passwords is irrelevant, just think of them as string1, string2, string3, etc.  I have added the `C#` and `.NET` tags to help get your question answered...

Comment: Thanks Ergin. I tried to use string1, string 2, etc. but I got a DocuSign error - invalid user name and password. But maybe I did not do it right. Hope to get more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified web.config as below. and then modified to use the key strings in the code.

```
<add key="p1" value=""/>
<add key="p1Pwd" value=""/>
<add key="p2" value=""/>
<add key="p2Pwd" value=""/>
<add key="p3" value=""/>
<add key="p3Pwd" value=""/>
<add key="p4" value=""/>
<add key="p5Pwd" value=""/>
```